# How to simplify infinite multiple?

Tags: notation, factorial

I have a series like

$$1!2!3! ... n!$$

for some finite n. How do I write this in notation? Similar to summation I guess or if it can simply be reduced down to something in terms of n that would be better. Is it $n!!$?

Thanks

Comment: The title is in contradiction with the body of the question. Moreover, $n!!$ is called double factorial and is a totally different thing. I don't think there's a specific notation for your case.

Comment: $\prod_{r=1}^{n}r!$ and $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r!$

Comment: How is that an infinite multiple?

Comment: It can be written as $\prod_{r=1}^n r^{n-r}$

Answer (score 3):

Well i can only assume what you are looking for. By the term in your question i think you might mean a superfactorial.
See [this Wikipedia Article on Factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Superfactorial) - it might help.

If you mean a product of factorials it would be a notation like
$$ sf(n)=\prod^n_{k=1}k!$$

Answer (score 0):

$n!!$ often denotes the semi-factorial, i.e. the product of every other integer up to $n$.